# populate a array from a JavaScript response

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to take a response from my database that is in a JSON array. In this case, the array has 4 elements.
I get how many elements in the response array "arrayLength"
Init the new array with the same number of elements
then I try and populate the array from the database response.
this code does not work not sure why or what i am doing wrong.

```
console.log('$response',$response.CardList[0].CNUMBER);  

var count = 0;
var i = 0
var arrayLength = $response.CardList.length;
console.log("my lenghth=",arrayLength );


var cardNumberArray =new Array[arrayLength];
console.log("my lenghth2=",cardNumberArray );


for ( i = 0; i < arrayLength ; i++ ){
  cardNumberArray[i] = JSON.stringify($response.CardList[i].CNUMBER)

}
```

Comment: `new Array[arrayLength]` -> `new Array(arrayLength)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `cardNumberArray` as an `Array`, but then selecting an index, which is done using `[]` square brackets. This index doesn't exist, so it's returning `undefined`. You're then selecting and index from `undefined`, which is what's giving you the error, which is `Cannot read property 'i' of undefined`.

How you would fix it, is to replace the square brackets with normal brackets, like this.

```js
let $response={CardList:[{CNUMBER:0},{CNUMBER:1},{CNUMBER:2},{CNUMBER:3}]}

var count = 0;
var i = 0
var arrayLength = $response.CardList.length;


var cardNumberArray =new Array(arrayLength);


for ( i = 0; i < arrayLength ; i++ ){
  cardNumberArray[i] = JSON.stringify($response.CardList[i].CNUMBER)

}
console.log(cardNumberArray)
```

Comment: If it helped, could you click the green checkmark next to this question?